# Custom metrics using grok with logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to integrate some code into an existing ELK stack, and we're limited to using filebeats + logstash. I'd like to have a way to configure a grok filter that will allow different developers to log messages in a pre-defined format such that they can capture custom metrics, and eventually build kibana dashboards.

For example, one team might log the following messages:

```
metric_some.metric=2
metric_some.metric=5
metric_some.metric=3
```

And another team might log the following messages from another app:

```
metric_another.unrelated.value=17.2
metric_another.unrelated.value=14.2
```

Is there a way to configure a single grok filter that will capture everything after `metric_` as a new field, along with the value? Everything I've read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match) seem to indicate that you need to know the field name ahead of time, but my goal is to be able to start logging new metrics without having to add/modify grok filters.

*Note: I realize Metricsbeat is probably a better solution here, but as we're integrating with an existing ELK cluster which we do not control, that's not an option for me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your messages seems to be a series of key-value pairs, you can use the `kv` filter instead of `grok`.

When using `grok` you need to name the destination field, with `kv` the name of the destination field will be the same as the `key`.

The following configuration should work for your case.

```
filter { kv { prefix => "metric_" } }
```

For the event `metric_another.unrelated.value=17.2` your output will be something like `{ "another.unrelated.value": "17.2" }`

Comment: Thanks, I do think `kv` is probably closer to what I need. However the `prefix` argument actually gets prepended to each entry: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-prefix

Comment: Oh, You are right, I thought it was the inverse, but it is no problem, I think that you can use the `remove_char_key` parameter from the `kv` filter to remove any prefix you have in the name of your fields.

Comment: So this got me really close. I ended up having to use a filter config that contained both `mutate` and `kv` because the metrics data I cared about was buried inside a log4j message. The `mutate` filter gave me a clean way to parse away all the extra log4j stuff (thread ID, class name, etc) and just get to raw metric string.